# Let P(n) denote some predicate. Suppose we prove the following premises:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Discrete math

Let P(n) denote some predicate. Suppose we prove the following
premises:

P(0)

P(1)

P(n)-->P(n + 2) for n>=0.

For what values of n can we conclude P(n) is true?

I found this under induction. I have no idea how to proceed. any pointers/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: To begin with, ask yourself the following questions. Do the premises allow you to conclude $P(2)$? Why or why not? What about $P(3)$?

Comment: I can't conclude anything beyond the premises. regardless of the n-value i choose, as am not given a value for p(0),p(1).

Comment: $P(n)$ is not a number: it’s some statement about the number $n$, and it’s not necessary to know what statement it is. Your premises are that this statement is true of $0$ and $1$, and that if it’s true of $n$, then it’s also true of $n+2$. Can you tell from this whether it’s true of $2$? Of $3$?

Comment: yes, if it true of p(0), p(1) then its true for 2 and 3.  if it's true for 2,3 would that mean that it is true for all value >=0 in the same way?

Comment: Now you have the idea. Knowing that $P(0)$ is true and that $P(n)\to P(n+2)$, you can conclude (by ordinary induction) that $P(2n)$ is true for $n\ge 0$. Similarly, from $P(1)$ you get that $P(2n+1)$ is true for $n\ge 0$. Putting those together, you get $P(n)$ true for all $n\ge 0$.